# When submitting feedback to a company on jobs you then can no longer ask the company a question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

The **ask a question** button disappears after you've provided a company with feedback.

Scenario - I gave company X some feedback like so:

[image]

I selected the last option which reads **I don't have a question but I have feedback about this job**.  Upon saving / submitting I do not have the opportunity to ask Company X any more questions.

After this feedback is given I wanted to ask Company X a question.

I question this functionality and whether this should happen or not?  If you are selecting item 3 in the radio button list you should be able to continue asking Company X questions.

Maybe to take it a step further should we ever hide this button after any question - not just feedback?

Comment: Agree that the UX around this feature is odd. We're revisiting the Ask/Feedback feature as part of our 2017 roadmap. Don't have a definite schedule yet, but hoping that this will be one of the items we handle as part of Q1/Q2.

Comment: I removed the [status-review] tag from this post because the Jobs product no longer exists.

Comment: @Slate - someone finally takes action after years only to close it because jobs is well gone.  Holy crap you cannot make this stuff up.